# Alert ID of element when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to figure out how to display this span's ID in an alert when the span is clicked. More specifically, I need it to display "Movie" so that I can select spans by "Movie" later on.

How can this be achieved? Thank you.

http://jsfiddle.net/neowot/x4yfracg/2/

HTML

```
<div id="Movie" class="Fun">

    <div class="lister">
        <ul class="active"><span>Rodeo</span></ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.lister ul span {
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).on('click', '.lister ul span', function(event) {  
            alert( $(this).attr('id') );
    }); 

});
```

Comment: the `span` doesnt have an id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
$(document).on('click', '.lister ul span', function(event) {  
    console.log( $(this).closest("div").parent().attr("id"));
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `closest` searching for `".Fun"` on ancestors in the DOM tree:

```
$(document).on('click', '.lister ul span', function(event) {  
        alert( $(this).closest(".Fun").attr('id') );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x4yfracg/5/

More information about `closest()` function: https://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).on('click', '.lister', function (event) {
        alert($(this).find('span').attr('id'));
        alert($(this).parent().attr('id'));
    });

});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/x4yfracg/3/)

`First put an attr id to span.`
What you can do is put the click event to `class lister` then get the id of the span found inside of that class.Then use `.parent()` to get its parent and you can now get the parents id as well